# how can i upload larger files into azure hadoop cluster?

Tags: azure, hadoop, mapreduce

how can i upload larger files into azure hadoop cluster?

Is there a way i can browse to the /example/apps directory in hadoop cluster by taking remote desktop connection so that i can copy the files?

Answer (score 1):

HDInsight uses Windows Azure Blob storage (WASB).  There are several ways you can upload data to WASB:

- AzCopy
- Windows Azure PowerShell
- 3rd party tools include Azure Storage Explorer, Cloud Storage Studio 2, CloudXplorer and so on.
- Hadoop command line. You must enable RDP first.

For more information, see http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/hdinsight/howto-upload-data-to-hdinsight/.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the files to Azure Blob Storage via HTTP/HTTPS and then MapReduce them from Hadoop on Azuure (HDInsight) by pointing at the HTTP URL of the uploaded file(s).

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for your response!! I would like to run a map reduce job which requires the dll to be in HDFS. So, is there any option to transfer the dll(7mb) to hdfs?

Comment: I'm not sure, never tried it (looks possible via an external job, probably simpler ways too), did find this information and blog post "Hadoop Streaming is a utility to support running external map and reduce jobs. These external jobs can be written in various programming languages such as Python or Ruby – should we talk about Microsoft HDInsight, the example better be based on .NET C#…" http://bighadoop.wordpress.com/2012/12/06/microsoft-and-hadoop-windows-azure-hdinsight/